# Befriending specific specialization works in gcc and msvc but not in clang

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, template-specialization, friend

I want to make a single specialization a friend as shown below. I tried the following with C++20 but the program gets *rejected by clang and is accepted by GCC and MSVC.*

```
template <class T> 
struct Ext {
   
   struct Inner
   { 
       int m{};
   };
   /*Is there a way to make this specialization work with all the compilers?
     Note that I know that I can write template<typename S> friend void fun2(Ext<T>::Inner&)
     but I only want to make this specialization a friend
   */
   friend void fun2<T>(typename Ext<T>::Inner&); //C++20: works in gcc and msvc but rejected by clang   
};

template <class T>
void fun2(typename Ext<T>::Inner &p) 
{ 
     p.m = 10; 
}
int main()
{
    Ext<int>::Inner x; 
    fun2<int>(x); 
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bYGWz4q4c)

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to make that specialization `void fun2<T>(typename Ext<T>::Inner&);` a friend so that the program is accepted by all compilers? That is, I want a workaround for making this particular specialization a friend instead of all `Ext`.
2. Is the program shown above(in my post) well-formed in C++20?

---

Clang says:

```
<source>:13:16: error: no candidate function template was found for dependent friend function template specialization
   13 |    friend void fun2<T>(typename Ext<T>::Inner&); //C++20: works in gcc and msvc but rejected by clang   
      |                ^
<source>:24:15: error: use of undeclared identifier 'x'
   24 |     fun2<int>(x);
```

Comment: I guess you meant `instantiation`, rather than `specialization`; the meaning of the two is quite different. So, I suggest that you edit. Also, if this is the minimum reproducible sample, It'd be better if you included the diagnostic message too. Last point, did you try putting definition of `fun2` above `Ext`, or at least provide a forward declaration for `fun2` template?

Comment: @Red.Wave It is not possible because it has a parameter of type `Ext<T>::Inner`.

Comment: @WeijunZhou that just proves the point: Befriending an instance of an undefined template. It would be seen clearer if the diagnostic message was present.

Comment: Hard to find a workaround for this as we can't provide a forward declaration for `fun2` before `Ext`.

Comment: @Red.Wave I think OP is using the right word. "Specialization" has two meanings: either an explicit/partial one, or a templated entity with specific arguments substituted. "Instantiation" is a process of generating a specialization from a template.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat please spot the specialization in the snippet. I don't think the freind declaration could be called specialization.

Comment: @Red.Wave `fun2<T>` is a specialization of `fun2`. They're not calling the friend declaration itself one, rather it refers to a specialization.

Comment: OP was indeed using the wrong phrase "explicit specialization" in the title but now that has been fixed and the word "specialization" itself is correct in this context.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thank.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the program is **ill-formed** and gcc and msvc are wrong in accepting the program.

First note that `fun2<T>` refers to a specialization of a function template. From [temp.friend](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.friend):

> 1. **A friend of a class or class template can be a** function template or class template, **a specialization of a function template** or class template, or a non-template function or class. **For a friend function declaration that is not a template declaration**:
>
>    1.1) **if the name of the friend is a qualified or unqualified template-id, the friend declaration refers to a specialization of a function template**, otherwise,
>
>    1.2)
>
>    1.3)
>
>    1.4)

---

Next, From [temp.deduct.decl](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.deduct.decl):

> 1. **In a declaration whose declarator-id refers to a specialization of a function template, template argument deduction is performed to identify the specialization to which the declaration refers.**
>    Specifically, **this is done for** explicit instantiations, explicit specializations, and **certain friend declarations.**
>    This is also done to determine whether a deallocation function template specialization matches a placement operator new ([basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation], [expr.new]).
>    In all these cases, P is the type of the function template being considered as a potential match and A is either the function type from the declaration or the type of the deallocation function that would match the placement operator new as described in [expr.new].
>    The deduction is done as described in [temp.deduct.type].
> 2. **If, for the set of function templates so considered, there is either no match or more than one match after partial ordering has been considered ([temp.func.order]), deduction fails and, in the declaration cases, the program is ill-formed.**

(emphasis mine)

And in our example, the set is empty and so there is no match which implies that the program is ill-formed as per the above quoted reference.